# MySQL select all dates that are an increment of x days

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Is it possible to query for **all** dates in the future that are an increment of x days?

i.e.

```
SELECT * 
FROM bookings 
WHERE date >= CURDATE()
AND 
(
       date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY 
   OR  date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 12 DAY
   OR  date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 18 DAY
   etc.
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM table
WHERE
    date >= CURDATE()
    AND
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date) % 6 = 0
```

[Datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns the number of days difference, and `% 6` says return the remainder when divided by six.

Comment: Ha, so simple yet awesome! Thank you, @scragar

Answer (score -3):

Yes.
Your logic is flawed, though. You probably meant

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
    date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 6 DAY 
OR  date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 12 DAY
OR  date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 18 DAY
```

And don't use table names like "table" and field names like "date" (i.e. reserved words).

Comment: You misinterpreted the question. OP wants more like every 6th day in the future.

Comment: You're right. Somehow I skipped the first line of the question.